# Java dealing with callback inside a function

Tags: java, android

I have a Java (Android) code that has callback, now I want to extract that code to its separate function for reusability, here is what I have:

```
InternQuery query = InternQuery.builder().build();

ApolloCall<InternQuery.Data> apolloCall = new HoraApolloClient(this.context).getHoraApolloClient().query(query);
        apolloCall.enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<InternQuery.Data>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<InternQuery.Data> response) {
                InternQuery.Data rData = response.data();
                // some error handling code ...
                InternQuery.Intern intern = rData.intern();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) { }
        });
```

Here you can see I am using Android Apollo client for GraphQL. So I have a function .enqueue which has a callback, in callback onResponse I can get my intern object.

Now I want to take this code into seperate method in a InternApi class, so code will loke something like that:

```
public InternsQuery.Intern getIntern() {
  // the code above goes here ...
}
```

The problem here is that How can I return from that function my intern object, as .enqueue is asynchronous, and my getIntern function will return earlier, I need to make it wait my callback.

Generally I guess, I need something like async/await. So I expect my code to be something like that:

```
public InternsQuery.Intern getIntern() {

  InternsQuery.Intern intern = await apolloCall.enqueue();

  return intern;

}
```

Is there async/await in java, or any other way of solving it?

Ideally I want it in a functional way, so my getIntern method returns intern. I believe I could pass reference to intern object that I create earlier and assign it in my callback, but it seems to be a bad solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't Futures used for that?

Comment: @KaranModi, I dont know what Futures is, but will google now. Thanks

Comment: Please note Java != Javascript. Don't use JS code snippets to mark your code. Indent by 4 spaces or hit ctrl + K. Thank you.